# bundle.js not building with webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, bundle

This is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './frontend/waitlist.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps'
};
```

When running rails s, on port 3000, it only renders rails view not rendering my react side, which is connected to the root in rails view 
(root.html.erb).

```
<main id="root"></main>
<h1> from root.html.erb file </h1>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bundle.js" %>
```

./frontend/waitlist.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const root = document.getElementById('root');
  ReactDOM.render(<h1>react render</h1>, root);
});
```

Do I have to run the webpack separately? or should 'rails s' command be fine with it?

Comment: Could be wrong, but is it possible that your document.addEventListener is being attached after the DOMContentLoaded event has already fired? I usually just run ReactDOM.render outside of an event listener in my entry point.

Comment: This is fine, but my bundle.js is not being built.